# Como leer caracteres y palabras en archivos en C?

Tags: c, archivo

tengo el siguiente ejercicio :

Desarrollar un algoritmo que lea dicho un archivo y cuente la
cantidad de palabras, la cantidad de líneas y la cantidad de caracteres del mismo.
Mostrar los resultados por pantalla.

*Yo ya cree el archivo de texto en la carpeta y me lee, pero no la cantidad correcta, solo los saltos de linea me da el número correcto, esto es lo que hice en Codeblocks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char espacio=' ';
    char c;
    int acumC=0,acumP=0,acumS=0;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("Mitexto.txt","rt");

    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            acumC++;
            if(espacio==fgetc(fp))
            {
                acumP+=1;
            }
            if(fgetc(fp)=='\n')
            {
                acumS++;
            }

        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    printf("En el texto hay: \n");
    printf("%d caracteres \n",acumC);
    printf("%d palabras \n",acumP);
    printf("%d saltos de linea \n",acumS);
    return 0;
}
```

Gracias por cualquier consejo o ayuda que me puedan brindar !

Answer (score 1):

Tu primer problema es que hay chequeos que no estás haciendo. Cada vez que llamas a `fgetc` estás consumiendo un caracter del archivo. En tu caso, consumes dos caracterse en cada iteración del bucle:

```
if(espacio==fgetc(fp)) // Consumes un caracter
{
    acumP+=1;
}
if(fgetc(fp)=='\n')    // Consumes otro caracer
{
    acumS++;
}
```

Esto te impide llevar una cuenta correctamente (prueba a añadir un salto de línea al inicio del archivo o en una posición impar, verás como ese salto de línea no lo cuenta).

Lo que tienes que hacer es recuperar el caracter y almacenarlo en una variable, para poder usarlo en diferentes comprobaciones:

```
char actual = fgetc(fp);
if(actual==' ')
{
    acumP+=1;
}
else if(actual=='\n')
{
    acumS++;
}
```

Por otro lado, podríamos definir como palabra como la agrupación de 1 o más caracteres, aislados de otras formaciones por lo que se conocen como delimitadores (espacios, tabuladores, saltos de línea, comas, puntos, ...)

Así que `acumP`, variable que yo renombraría quizás a `acumuladorPalabras` (procura que los nombres de las variables signifiquen algo), se debería incrementar de una forma un poco más compleja:

```
int palabraEncontrada = 0;

while(!feof(fp))
{
    char actual = fgetc(fp);
    if(isalpha(actual))
    {
        palabraEncontrada = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if( palabraEncontrada )
            acumuladorPalabras++;
        palabraEncontrada = 0;     
    }

    if(actual==' ')
    {
        acumP+=1;
    }
    else if(actual=='\n')
    {
        acumS++;
    }
}
```

Por supuesto hay que tener en cuenta que el archivo puede terminar con una palabra, sin que haya un espacio, un punto o cualquier otro delimitador:

```
int palabraEncontrada = 0;

while(!feof(fp))
{
    // ...
}

if( palabraEncontrada )
    acumuladorPalabras++;
```